# Is there any method to get html tag on specific height?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can get height of entire container using jQuery, I want to add H1 tag after 500px height inside the container.

```
var height = $("body").find(".container"). innerHeight();
if(height > 800){
 //Get here div on height 600 and insertAfter('<h1>New Heading</h1>') after that element on height 600, and insert H1 tag after closing that specific element  
}

var height = $("body").find(".container"). innerHeight();
if(height > 800){
 //Get here div on height 600 and insertAfter('<h1>New Heading</h1>') after that element on height 600, insert H1 tag right after specific element  
}
```

Comment: You can achieve this with css just put a margin-top of 500px in h1

Comment: What do you mean by "get html tag on specific height"? Do you want the h1 to be placed inside the container and 500px space between the top of the container and the h1? Please post some html and css so we can help you better.

Comment: @Whoami-github I don't need to put margin of 500px, I want to add h1 tag after 500px.

Comment: @ArturNoetzel I want to know the the element inside container from the top of 500px, then add h1 tag.

Comment: sir I have a table inside container , there are many rows in that table, and I want to print that table, I have fixed header and footer for that too, now I just want page break if the container have more than 800px height, there should be h1 tag added after 500px from the top, then I'll apply page break for that. content inside container is generating dynamically, I want to use a logic to check which <tr> is on 500px from the top , rest of the logic I can apply. I hope you understood the question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly
you can accomplish this with some styles:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <h3 class="customTag">Im Your H3</h3>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    height: 800px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: red;
}
.customTag{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 500px;
    background-color: yellow;
    }
```

Here is demo for you:
https://codepen.io/init1/pen/ExxpxoM

Comment: sir I have a table inside container , there are many rows in that table, and I want to print that table, I have fixed header and footer for that too, now I just want page break if the container have more than 800px height, there should be h1 tag added after 500px from the top, then I'll apply page break for that. content inside container is generating dynamically, I want to use a logic to check which <tr> is on 500px from the top , rest of the logic I can apply. I hope you understood the question, thanks

Comment: Have you got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(window).bind('scroll', function() { 
    var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 600; 
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight){
      $('.header').addClass('headcolor'); $('.nave_stickey_text').fadeIn(); 
    } else { 
      $('.header').removeClass('headcolor'); 
      $('.nave_stickey_text').fadeOut(); 
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: sir I have a table inside container , there are many rows in that table, and I want to print that table, I have fixed header and footer for that too, now I just want page break if the container have more than 800px height, there should be h1 tag added after 500px from the top, then I'll apply page break for that. content inside container is generating dynamically, I want to use a logic to check which <tr> is on 500px from the top , rest of the logic I can apply. I hope you understood the question, thanks